# How to reply to answers on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, user-interface

I asked a question on Tumblr and ticked the "Let people answer this" option. Now a few answers have come in, and I wanted to reply to them, yet I do not see a way how.

Is it possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Is [this](http://tumblring.net/replying-to-a-reply-on-tumblr-is-it-possible/) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bad news, you can’t reply back to replies that were left in your own posts. However, if you have [Discus Comments](http://disqus.com/) installed, that would be the solution, so you can start using that addon instead of allowing replies, which is an old and not very complete Tumblr feature.

<sub>Source: [tumblring.net](http://tumblring.net/replying-to-a-reply-on-tumblr-is-it-possible/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you install [missing-e](http://missing-e.com/) you can make posts [like this](http://guilmongivesreallygoodbread.tumblr.com/post/27751931024) easily, but they are not tracked by post notes.